# Add an event to Outlook/iCal/Google Calendar in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, calendar

Is it possible to add an event directly to a user's calendar (be it google, iCal, Outlook) with AS3?  I work at a major network and my boss wants to add this functionality to our Flash banners to help promote our TV shows.  The best I can think of is having a button that links out to a .ics file the the user downloads and adds manually, but I'd like to avoid having the user do anything other than click on a button.

Any advice/direction is much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? Are you using ActionScript? Can you add more detail to your answer? It is too general, and could possibly be closed.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to develop some kind of mediator that takes your request and then translates it into platform specific API calls (if any exist). For example, you would need to use the [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/) to add events directly into a Google Calendar.